# Найти значение из списка путем сравнения

Tags: python

Не могу понять как написать. Нужно перебрать в date1 даты из date2. Это списки разной длинны и если в date2 будет дата, которая равняется date1 (первая попавшаяся только) - то нужно по номеру которым стоит дата в date2 (номер i например, date2 и kelvin одинаковой длинны) - найти число в kelvin значение соответсвующее этому же номеру.

```
for i in range(len(data)-1):
   if date1[i] in ....
```

```
date1 = ['2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-03', ...]

date2 = ['2014-04-01','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-04','2014-04-05','2014-04-06', ...]
kelvin = [102,101,100,103,102,101, ...]
```

Пример - '2014-04-02' из date1 соотвествует '2014-04-02' из date2 под номером 2. kelvin под номером 2 равен 101.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что вы ожидаете в результате ?

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я понял вам нужно перебрать первый список с датами и найти те, которые есть во втором. Это можно сделать с помощью цикла for и каждый раз проверять есть ли дата во втором списке. Если есть, то находить индекс первой попавшейся даты и брать элемент из списка `kelvin`. Примерно так:

```
date1 = ['2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-03']
date2 = ['2014-04-01','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-04','2014-04-05','2014-04-06']
kelvin = [102,101,100,103,102,101]
result = []
for date in date1:
    if date in date2:
        result.append(kelvin[date2.index(date)])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваши пожелания весьма туманны. Я понял так:

```
date1 = ['2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-03']
date2 = ['2014-04-01','2014-04-02','2014-04-03','2014-04-04','2014-04-05','2014-04-06']
kelvin = [102,101,100,103,102,101]

d = {k:v for k,v in zip(date2,kelvin)}
for i in date1:
    print(d[i])
'''
101
101
101
100
100
```